# optimize SQL query with multiple JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

how to optimize this query and increase its performance,

```
SELECT user.id,user.name,profile.info,score.amount
FROM user
LEFT JOIN profile ON profile.user_id = user.id AND profile.type = 'language'
LEFT JOIN score ON score.user_id = user.id AND score.type = 'total'
WHERE email = 'example@mail.com'
```

return results:

```
[id]       =>    1060225
[name]     =>    john
[info]     =>    En
[ammount]  =>    533
```

return results 2:

```
[id]       =>    1022805
[name]     =>    karin
[info]     =>    
[ammount]  =>    11
```

tables:

users table

```
id     name         email
1      john      example@mail.com
2      karin     tt@kkk.com
3      Tom       kk@yahoo.com
4      kit       mm@gmail.com
```

profile table

```
id     user_id       type          info
1        1          is_admin       true
2        1          language        En
3        1          active         true
4        2          is_admin       false
1        1          like           null
2        2          favorite       null
3        3          is_admin       false
4        2          experience       4
```

score table

```
id     user_id     type     amount
1         1        daily      33
2         1        total      533
3         2        total      11
4         3        daily      44
```

thanks,

Comment: Use `explain ... ` to find out where you need an index.

Comment: @Jens where to put "explain" in the query

Comment: at the beginning. `explian select ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, p.info, s.amount
FROM user u LEFT JOIN
     profile p
     ON p.user_id = u.id AND p.type = 'language' LEFT JOIN
     score s
     ON s.user_id = u.id AND s.type = 'total'
WHERE u.email = 'example@mail.com';
```

(I just added table aliases to make the query more readable and to clarify where the columns come from.)

Try the following indexes:

```
create index idx_user_email_id_name on user(email, id, name);
create index idx_profile_userid_type on profile(user_id, type);
create index idx_score_userid_type on score(user_id, type);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give the `profile` and `score` tables composite indexes on `(type, user_id)`. I'm not sure whether it will be better to have `type` or `user_id` first in the indexes, you should try each of them and see which is better; you can use `EXPLAIN` to compare the execution plans for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating indexes on the join columns (if not there already), and using subqueries instead of joins:

```
SELECT 
  id,
  name,
  (select info from profile where user_id = user.id AND type = 'language') as "info", 
  (select amount from score where user_id = user.id and type = 'total') as "amount"
FROM user
WHERE email = 'example@mail.com'
```

Other tips: Check the execution plan, add indexes to avoid full table scans where appropriate, denormalize tables by duplicating some data if necessary or using views.

Comment: when try subquries just took same time as join

Comment: Is it running slow enough to cause problems? other things you could do is implement caching in your application (for user id and name, for example) instead of querying from the database each time. You could also move the info and amount columns into the user table, or duplicate them on update. If you've verified that indexes are being used there's still several things you could try, including: hardware upgrades, lookup tables, app-level caching, full-text index, etc. Make sure `user.email` is indexed if that is what you search on. Try using connection pooling to reduce startup/teardown time..

Comment: but duplicate tables columns is not best thing to do ? isn't it?

Comment: @nothingisnecessary . . . This is not necessarily the same query.  The first could return multiple rows for a given user if there are multiple matches in either table.